# How can i fix Inline Assembly in Code blocks?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

*What did i did wrong?*

```
**#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int x,y,vysled=0;
int main()
{
    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix \n"
       "mov eax,_x              \n"
       "add eax,_y              \n"
       "mov _vysled,eax         \n"
       ".att_syntax             \n");
    printf("%d + %d = %d",x,y,vysled);
    return 0;
}**
```

*building log prints Undefined reference to _x,_y.*

Comment: What compiler are you programming for?  This looks like you attempt to use MSVC-style inline assembly with gcc's syntax which won't work.

Comment: @fuz: It's GNU C Basic asm, not MSVC.  Still very bad, but the variables are global so this actually *could* compile with the right asm symbol names to match the target platform.  But it would be unsafe other than in a debug build.  (clobbering EAX, and asm reading and writing memory without a "memory" clobber or listing them as input or output operands).  Dávid - see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info